# html5blank pagination not working

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

```
<?php 
/* Template Name: Front page */ 
get_header(); 
?>

<div class="rfp_hide" id="rhm_show">
    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'page' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'product_cat' => '',
        'orderby' => 'date',            
        'order' => 'DESC'
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global  $post, $paged; 
    ?>

    <div class="rhm_container">
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[show_post]'); ?>  
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>  
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; PREV', $loop->max_num_pages) ?></li> 
            <li><?php next_posts_link( 'NEXT &raquo;', $loop->max_num_pages) ?></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>  
</main><!--/main content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So, this is my html5blank template that I have which shows posts.

I can't seem to be able to make the pagination work.

Well, that's not entirely true. I can see the "Next" button at the bottom. The href is `example.com/page/2`. However when I click it, it just refreshes the page and does not go to page 2.

Does anyone know why it might be like that?

Thank!

Comment: Try replacing wp_reset_query() by wp_reset_postdata(). wp_reset_query() resets the global query and wp_reset_postdata() only restores the current $post variable.

Comment: paged not page , in your wp_query arguments [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)

Comment: So, I did some testing. the above code works just fine when it is not in a home page. However when it is in a home page, the page simply refreshes and does not show the second page content. How can I fix this?

Comment: So, I got it working once I knew what the problem was: Add `if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {

   $paged = get_query_var('paged');

  } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {

   $paged = get_query_var('page');

  } else {

   $paged = 1;

  }` and you are good to go! =)